# Migrating ASp.net webform based websites to Microsoft Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, webforms, migration, azure-web-app-service

I have to migrate asp.net webform & asp.net MVC websites to Microsoft Azure and most of the webform based website have been created as "website project" in visual studio. and all website use MS SQL Server 2008  R2 as database plus all website use either .net Framework 4.0/4.5.

I confused by reading article regarding migrating webform based website to Azure not working and need code changes and if we use Azure database then we cant use stored procedures etc... this has confused me alot.

So i have few question regarding this.

1. Can i move asp.net webform 4.0 based website directly to Azure without making any code changes assuming we are connecting to external SQL SERVER 2008.
2. For first step can which MS SQL Server database i need to choose on Azure so that i can easily restore database in Azure and connect to this database from my local machine using MS Management Studio..
3. I have heard lot about Azure store files as blob and we need to make change to code to point to new path. What is this Azure blob and why do we need to change code for pointing them blob.
4. What i have to do keep allowing users from uploading images & document without making any changes in the code..
5. Does Azure website have always 1 instance running or multiple instance running, i am asking this as our website use InProc session state will i lose session if it is ruuning on multiple instance. or should we prefer SQL Session state in Azure enviroment.

What i should take into consideration for migration current website to Azure.

Will copy pasting all the files in Azure work. Please advise

Comment: create a (free) account, upload one site and test it

Comment: that process should take about 10 minutes max

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how old the ASP.NET webforms projects are, you are going to need to bring them up to date with current security, and anti forgery tokens, etc.

Also if the project was previously a "Website" and not a "Web Application", this is also something that you will need to take into consideration!

I am currently working on upgrading a website to a web application.

This might be a useful website to look through 
http://www.gregthatcher.com/Azure/Ch7_ConvertWebsiteToWebApplication.aspx

Comment: Appreciate your feebdback, Since you have experience same could you please let me know what changes you are making to convert project from `website` to `web application` and if you are facing any issues  with same..

Comment: Just to mention all our website project are asp.net 4.0 & 4.5

Comment: I had a ASP.NET 2.0 Website that I am re developing to ASP.NET 4.5.

I will look thought my notes. Good tip though, is work on creating a Template ASP.NET framework Web Application and then you can use this as your base for all other work. 

Logging in used to be done with ASPNET Membership, it now uses OWIN. So I will be needing to import the users from the old system across when I am finished working on the conversion.

Answer (score -2):

Migrating to Azure is easy ,
create a Azure account and create the web app which you want to host or create.
you can deploy using FTP or use the build and deploy feature in TFS account.

Steps

1. You need to create web app in your account.
2. create a DB in azure manually or export your DB to azure from Management studio if you have an existing DB
3. get the Connection string from the Publish profile from Azure.
4. Setup the storage account if you want to store files ,images etc.

Comment: "*Migrating to Azure is easy*" - I would suggest eliminating this. What's easy to you might not be easy to someone else. And your steps are not necessarily how things work (and skip the not-easy parts). Especially step 4, where both URLs and code have to be changed, to support working with content in Azure Storage blobs (since there's no direct file I/O). And in step 2, how do you propose the OP handle the case where a feature in SQL Server isn't supported in SQL Database? And how to choose between database-as-a-service and SQL Server VM?

Comment: @DavidMakogon, For these reason i want advice from user who have experience with this. As per `Nitin` it sounds easy but i have read article where users have issues and some had to make lot of code changes to make there website work on Azure. For this reason i am extra caution about Azure..

Comment: @DavidMakogon, Could you please advice what approach i should take to migrate to Azure taking into consideration that we have website developed in asp.net webforms 4.0 and some website in ASP.net MVC 5. besides this our websites are hosted on Dedicated server and now we want to move to very reliable source such as Azure. i have lot of question regarding this like Database, Failover, are azure websites auto backed up, do these website have only one instance running on cloud so session variable are not lost etc..

Comment: @Learning - you missed my point here. It's not that you need to have "extra caution with Azure" - it's that stating something is "easy" to migrate can be misleading. We've never seen any of your code and have no idea what might work unchanged and what might need to be tweaked. This answer suggests using blob storage (a great idea, but... will require code tweaks).